# How can I get Office 365 users' licenses and friendly name of License?

Tags: office365

I want to get a list of Office 365 users with their assigned licenses with their friendly name. Is it possible to get through Microsoft 365 Admin center or any other option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Embry,

You can see user's assigned license through the Admin Center, but you can't view its friendly name. You need to use PowerShell for that. Save a license and its friendly name in a separate file(i.e., LicenseFriendlyName.txt)  and import them to script.

```
    $FriendlyNameHash=Get-Content -Raw -Path .\LicenseFriendlyName.txt -ErrorAction Stop | ConvertFrom-StringData
    Get-MsolUser -All | where{$_.islicensed -eq "true"} |Foreach-Object{
    $Skus=$_.licenses.accountSKUId 
    foreach($Sku in $Skus)  #License loop 
    {  
     #Convert Skuid to friendly name  
     $LicenseItem= $Sku -Split ":" | Select-Object -Last 1  
     $EasyName=$FriendlyNameHash[$LicenseItem]  
     if(!($EasyName))  
     {$FrndlyName=$LicenseItem}  
     else  
     {$FrndlyName=$EasyName}  
    }
```

If the license name present in the file, it gets converted to friendly name else License pack name will be shown.

I'd suggest using a pre-built script that is specifically designed for this job.
[Export Office 365 users license report using PowerShell](https://o365reports.com/2018/12/14/export-office-365-user-license-report-powershell/)

Comment: Where can I get a list of license name and their friendly name?

Comment: @EmbryFedora I have updated my comment. Check now. You can get license and its friendly name file here: [Office 365 Users licenses with friendly name](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Export-Office-365-User-079add3a)